# LINQ to Entities group-by failure using .date

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4, group-by

I am trying to do a Linq group by on just the date part of a datetime field.

This linq statement works but it groups by the date and the time.

```
var myQuery = from p in dbContext.Trends
          group p by p.UpdateDateTime into g
          select new { k = g.Key, ud = g.Max(p => p.Amount) };
```

When I run this statement to group by just the date I get the following error

```
var myQuery = from p in dbContext.Trends
          group p by p.UpdateDateTime.Date into g   //Added .Date on this line
          select new { k = g.Key, ud = g.Max(p => p.Amount) };
```

The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. 
Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

How can I do a group by for the date and not the date and time?

Comment: That is weird because the same exact code works for Linq to SQL!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) method:

```
var myQuery = from p in dbContext.Trends
          group p by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(p.UpdateDateTime) into g
          select new { k = g.Key, ud = g.Max(p => p.Amount) };
```

Comment: This works.  It is a little cleaner than the other solution which also works.  Thanks!

Comment: It works in all cases except when different timezones are used. Then the grouping is also done in timezones. Ive posted a bad solution here and would like som help to make the code cleaner: [.NET LINQ to entities group by date (day)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016703/net-linq-to-entities-group-by-date-day)

Answer (score 5):

Possible solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/cb58ae5f-5db9-4054-92b6-a1bf63764574) which follows the pattern:

```
var q = from i in ABD.Listitem
    let dt = p.EffectiveDate
    group i by new { y = dt.Year, m = dt.Month, d = dt.Day} into g
    select g;
```

So, for your query [untested]:

```
var myQuery = from p in dbContext.Trends
      let updateDate = p.UpdateDateTime
      group p by new { y = updateDate.Year, m = updateDate.Month, d = updateDate.Day} into g
      select new { k = g.Key, ud = g.Max(p => p.Amount) };
```

Comment: This works with one small mod.  "into g" must be added to the end of the third line.  Thanks!

Comment: But I would say adrift's solution is the better one if you're using EF 4.0 .. I wasn't previously aware of the EntityFunctions utils..

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `DateTime.Date` in an Linq-to-Entities query. You either have group by the fields explicitly or create a `Date` field in the database. (I had the same problem - I used a `Date` field in the db, never looked back).