# Group by DateTime.Date in Linq to SQL with EF 4.1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, group-by

I'm trying to work out how to group each item by the day it occurred within a time range in Linq to SQL, but I cannot get it working.

```
   var graph = from o in DB.Context.Occurances
            where o.Occurred > fromDate && o.Occurred <= toDate
            group o by o.Occurred.Date into g
            orderby g.Key ascending 
            select new
                       {
                           Date = g.Key,
                           Occurances = g.Count()
                       };
```

Every time I run this I get the error

> "The specified type member 'Date' is
>   not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are
>   supported."

Searching I found this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188066/linq-to-entities-group-by-failure-using-date) that addresses this issue... but when running this using Entity Framework, I get the exception

> "The function is not recognized by SQL
>   Server Compact. [ Name of function =
>   TRUNCATETIME,Data type (if known) = 
>   ]"

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use the second answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188066/linq-to-entities-group-by-failure-using-date has very clean answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I know of that will definitely work is to manually select a concatenation of the `Year`, `Month`, `Day` properties using `String.Concat` or integer arithmetic and group on that.

Source: [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.Occurred) to get Date in LINQ to SQL.