# Comparing date parts in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

In LINQ to SQL, how do I compare only the date part of an sql datetime column and .net datetime object?

Comment: I know EF doesn't support this translation, but LINQ to SQL might support using the `.Date` property on the DateTime for the comparison.  -- just checked, it does.  Link posted in my answer.

Comment: In EF, you can use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188066/linq-to-entities-group-by-failure-using-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `Date` property of both:

```
Date today = DateTime.Today; // Effectively DateTime.Now.Date

var dataFromToday = from record in context.Records
                    where record.TimeStamp.Date == today
                    select record;
```

I *believe* this works for LINQ to SQL... as tvanfosson says, it doesn't for EF.

Comment: I know that it doesn't.  That bit me yesterday.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Duly made more emphatic :)

Comment: A real pain, too, since I typically mock out the data context for unit tests and it does work with LINQ to objects (obviously).  I have to remember that when developing the repository that the unit tests can lie about stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL supports translation of the Date property to SQL for comparisons, etc.  More information on the supported options can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Data.Entity;

DbFunctions.TruncateTime(u.BirthDate) = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(someDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a CLR UDF to do the date only compare and then reference that in your linq to sql linq query.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient; //Don't forget this!!

//You can access to SQL DatePart function using something like this:

YourTable.Select(t => new { DayOfWeek = SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", t.dateTimeField) - 1 }); //Zero based in SQL

//You can compare to SQL DatePart function using something like this:

DateTime dateToCompare = DateTime.Today;
YourTable.Where(t => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", t.dateTimeField) - 1 == dateToCompare }); //Zero based in SQL
```