# .NET LINQ to entities group by date (day)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, timezone

I have the same problem posted here:
[LINQ to Entities group-by failure using .date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188066/linq-to-entities-group-by-failure-using-date)

However, the answer is not 100% correct. It works in all cases except when different timezones are used. When different timezones are used, it also groups on timezones. Why?
I managed to bypass this by using many entity functions.

```
int localOffset= Convert.ToInt32(
    TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes);

var results = (
    from perfEntry in db.entry
    where (....)
    select new { 
        perfEntry.Operation, perfEntry.Duration, 
        localTime = EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(perfEntry.Start, 
            localOffset - EntityFunctions.GetTotalOffsetMinutes(
                perfEntry.Start)) 
    }
).GroupBy(x => new { 
    Time = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(
        EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(x.localTime.Value.Year,
            x.localTime.Value.Month, x.localTime.Value.Day, 0, 0, 0)),
    x.Operation }
).OrderByDescending(a => a.Key).
Select(g => new {
    Time = g.Key.Time,
    ...
});
```

Is there someone out there who knows how to do this the proper way? This code is so ugly and probably very inefficient.

UPDATE (warning):
I also realised that the function EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime suffers from a bug. Its not compatible with leap years, such as this year. 29 feb 2012 will throw an exception.

Comment: Ugly code is not necessarily inefficient code.

Comment: yes, but such a simple operation should be able to write in a easier way?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Remember, that Linq to Entities must convert C# into SQL, that means it has many restrictions on what you can do to it because there is no SQL that supports the operation.  The EntityFunctions is there specifically to deal with these limitations, so you have to use them if you want what they do.

Comment: Using four EntityFunctions for one single task seams like overkill. Surely there must be an easier way...

Comment: IMO, sometimes the easiest way to to just write a sproc.  Up to you to decide when you're hitting that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UTC DateTime and trunkate the time after it.

Comment: You mean the DateTime function ToUniversalTime()? This does not work in linq to entities. You can only use a few functions and properties in linq to entities.

Comment: LinqToEntity try to convert your request to sql query. It can't translate ToUniversalTime() to Sql. I'd suggest you get all data first (.ToList() for example) and make any things with collection of the data. In the case you can use ToUTCTime() function in Linq query.

Comment: I am dealing with huge tables and complex statistics. To get all data first will have an impact on performance which im not willing to take.

Comment: Ok. In the case you have to make some sql work and align you date to UTC in SQL. You can use view to create the work. Sure, you'll keep your performance up. Additionally you can truncate time in the view. It'll be much more faster if you you use Dateadd and datediff functions.

Comment: ok, that seams to be a better solution, although i was hoping this could be solved without modifying the database. Are there sqlfunctions that can translate to UTC then?

Comment: i used that approach, however, thats not really an answer to my question, it should be possible to do in the business layer of the application.

Comment: Hope the topic will help you convert date to utc date by SQL query http://www.opsvault.com/how-to-convert-sql-server-datetime-data-to-utc-time/