# Linq to entities does not know what .Date operator is

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am getting an error saying linq to entities does not know about the `.Date` operator in the following query:

```
var data = from p in page_loads
           join f in sites
           on p.site_id equals f.id
           join tr in test_runs
           on p.test_run_id equals tr.id
           where f.id == 17
           group p by  p.created_at.Date into g
           select new { time = g.Average(t => t.time), created_at = g.Key };
```

**Note:** `created_at` is `NOT NULL` in the database. I am pointing this out because I know that created_at is not nullable and linq to entities would have issues with that. But I don't know how to fix this issue.

**Edit:**

```
[EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = false, IsNullable = false)]
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you show the page_loads class?

Comment: I just added the definition of just created_at because I thought that's all you probably need to take a look at.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you might want [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx):

```
group p by SqlFunctions.DatePart("day", p.created_at) into g
```

Comment: I still get this error:  `Server Error in '/' Application.
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported`

Comment: I think my issue is that `DatePart` wants `DateTime?` as its second argument but I am providing it `DateTime`. What do you think Jon? Is there any work around that?

Comment: @SherCoder: Sorry, edited - I meant to get rid of the `Date` property. Done now. Try again.

Comment: I get this after that change: `The specified method System.Nullabl1[System.Int32] DatePart(System.String, System.Nullable1[System.DateTime]) on the type System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.`

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. I thought the whole point of `SqlFunctions` was to avoid that problem... Which database are you using, out of interest?

Comment: It is a `MySQL` database. Maybe that's the issue

Comment: @SherCoder: Yes, almost certainly. `SqlClient` is for SQL Server databases. I wish you'd mentioned this before... you'll need to see if there's an equivalent `SqlFunctions` for MySQL.

Comment: I can't seem to anything related to mysql that would help. But do you think if I first pull all the time and created_at into `var` without getting the average and just the date part and then work with that `var`. wouldn't it be easier that way?

Comment: @SherCoder: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you're talking about fetching the data and working out the average locally, that would *work* - but it would be potentially much less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by other fields in the `DateTime` (creating a new unique anonymous object for each year/month/day combination) and you'll want to use `let` to simplify the query:

```
var data = from p in x
       join f in sites
       on p.site_id equals f.id
       join tr in test_runs
       on p.test_run_id equals tr.id           
       where f.id == 17
       let date = p.created_at
       group p by new { y = date.Year, m = date.Month, d = date.Day} into g
       select new { time = g.Average(t => t.time), created_at = g.Key };
```

If you want the `created_at` in your final projection to not be an anonymous type, you can convert the group-by anonymous type back into a `DateTime` by passing the 3 anonymous values to the `DateTime` constructor.

There are other solutions presented in the [answers to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188066/linq-to-entities-group-by-failure-using-date) that use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`.

Comment: That looks like its quite useful, but I don't understand what you mean by `convert the group-by anonymous type back into a DateTime...`. did you mean something like this: `group p by new DateTime { y = date.Year, m = date.Month, d = date.Day} into g`?

Comment: In your `select` do `created_at = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, g.Key.Day)`... but it looks like you could do what you said as well.

Comment: why does it give me `NotSupportedException` when I try to do this: ` var mydata = data.ToArray();`

Comment: Because it's truly not supported (yet): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362794/the-linq-expression-node-type-newarrayinit-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities