# Convert sql query into linq getting error in converting date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

My Sql Query Is:

```
select count(*),CONVERT(varchar, AddedOn, 101) 
from MemberNotifications where IsActive=1  
group by CONVERT(varchar, AddedOn, 101) 
order by CONVERT(varchar, AddedOn, 101) desc
```

but i m not able to get result, in following attempt

```
    List<NotificationCounts> lst =
(from mn in this.MemberNotifications 
 where  mn.UId.Equals(friendId) 
select new NotificationCounts{ NotificationDate = mn.AddedOn.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") })
.ToList<NotificationCounts>();
```

I want to get only list of date in string for mat but it is giving an exception

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Is there any solution for this error?

Comment: what is the type of `NotificationDate` in `NotificationCounts` class

Answer (score 0):

true... linq can't transform the .ToString into a SQL instruction... need to get the plain value of mn.AddedOn and transform it after the database get. Hope it helps

Comment: i have did it but i want to use group by on date and  AddedOn is a datetime field and i want group the rows only by Date

Comment: Retrive data to anonymous type and then you can use the ToString there. The only problem is when retrieving to database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call ToString() there because there is no translation to SQL.
You have to call `ToList()` first and after that you can manipulate the in memory object like you want:

```
List<NotificationCounts> lst =
    (from mn in this.MemberNotifications 
     where  mn.UId.Equals(friendId) 
     select 
       new { 
            NotificationDate = mn.AddedOn
       })
    .ToList()
    .Select(n => new NotificationCounts 
                  {
                      NotificationDate  = n.NotificationDate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")
                  });
```

**EDIT**: For grouping by date see this question: [LINQ to Entities group-by failure using .date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4188066/25727)
In short: Use the [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just save the string to a temp variable and then use that in your expression:

Sample:

```
var strItem = item.Key.ToString();
IQueryable<entity> pages = from p in context.pages
                           where  p.Serial == strItem
                           select p;
```

The problem is that ToString() isn't really executed, it is turned into a MethodGroup and then parsed and translated to SQL. Since there is no ToString() equivalent, the expression fails.
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method) for more infos

Answer (score 0):

Use this (Not tested)

```
List<NotificationCounts> lst = (from mn in this.MemberNotifications 
                                where  mn.UId.Equals(friendId) select mn).ToList()
                               .Select(mn=>new NotificationCounts
                               { 
                                  NotificationDate = mn.AddedOn.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") 
                               }).ToList();
```